# any number following ### regular expression

Tags: javascript

I am having string like below

```
###method:song:2###
```

also string like below

```
###method:song:2######method:movie:4###
```

Number 2 and 4 is not static its dynamic 0-9 any number come.

i need to replace the string like below
[image]

Can any one please help me to fix this.

I tried below for starting ### change

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('###method', 'gi'),'<div>###method');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ayt9S/417/

Comment: You included a screenshot of *text*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a capture group

match ###, anything but # more than one time, and ###

```js
var str = '###method:song:2######method:movie:4###'
console.log(str.replace(/(###[^#]+###)/g,"<div>$1</div>")) // keep #
console.log(str.replace(/###([^#]+)###/g,"<div>$1</div>")) // ignore #
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str.replace(/(###method:(song|movie):\d###)/, '<div>$1</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(/(###method:.+?:\d###)/gi, '<div>$1</div>')
```